# integrating vanilla forums and yii without iframes

Tags: php, yii, integration, forum, vanilla-forums

I'm trying to integrate Vanilla Forums with a Yii site that I built. Vanilla provides a really nifty embed feature to embed the forum on whatever page you like, the only issue is it uses iframes. iframes are not an option for what I'm trying to do, so I'm trying to figure out a more native way to do this. I need to have Vanilla display inside of my Yii layout.

I'm open to having vanilla be a subdomain or a subdirectory (or controller/action), I'm just trying to get this working without having to hack Vanilla or Yii too much.

Currently, I've included Yii's yii.php file inside of Vanilla's index.php file, and I can access Yii classes this way. But I'm not entirely sure how to render the Yii layout from inside of Vanilla. Can any of you help me out? Thanks!